# can you store flickr images from the php api to your own mysql table

Tags: php, flickr, phpflickr

can you store flickr images from the php api to your own mysql table, or is the server only temporary and farm id etc, will they change over time?

I am trying to make a simple pinterest type of script which I will store the image url to a mysql table and link through to them directly on my website.

is this possible or do they need to be saved.

Comment: I can't see why it can't be done. You'd be best just saving the images' URLs in rows, then accessing them through a loop with `<img src="...">`

Comment: i was only asking because i was wondering if they have some way of making it so you can only access the image for a short amount of time, e.g they switch the servers so the image is no longer hosted on the link that i first save in my mysql table

Comment: You'd be best saving the image on your own server then, if you're concerned about them potentially changing the URL. Don't save it as a blob in DB, but physically on your server. Doing a blob will dramatically increase the size of your DB over time.

Comment: thanks fred, post it as an answer if you'd like and ill tick it.

Comment: You're welcome, it has been done (as per your request), *cheers*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"thanks fred, post it as an answer if you'd like and ill tick it."*

*As per OP's request:*

You'd be best saving the image on your own server then, if you're concerned about them potentially changing the URL.

Don't save it as a blob in DB, but physically on your server. Doing a blob will dramatically increase the size of your DB over time.